# UA to GA4 Migration - Can we use the same GTM container used for UA

Tags: migration, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I am currently working on UA to GA4 migration. I want the UA and GA4 properties to exist in parallel for time being until the GA4 migration stabilizes. We implement GA via Google Tag Manager. I want to know whether the same GTM container associated with UA property can be used for GA4 property as well.

The GTM container already has Universal analytics tag. I tried to create the GA4 configuration tag in the same container and upon testing able to view the hits in both UA report and GA4 report. Kindly advise if this is a suggested solution.

Our customer has the GTM script, associated with UA property, already embedded in their website. We do not want rework at their end by providing new GTM script for GA4. That is why we would like to know if it it appropriate to use the same GTM container for both UA and GA4 properties, so that, no rework is required from the customer end.

Thanks,
Keerthana

Answer (score 0):

This is, indeed the industry practice at the moment to have all in one GTM container. That would include pretty much any TMS and tracking endpoint.

However, it's best to do such migrations with someone who knows their way around GTM/GA/Data. Especially if EEC or consent is involved. It gets tricky.